# Unir Arrays sin utilizar el método concat y devolverlo en un nuevo Array

Tags: javascript, array

Estoy realizando un ejercicio sencillo de hacer iterativamente o con el método `concat`, que consiste en unir 2 *arrays* y retornar lo unido como un nuevo *array*, pero no lo logro, este es el código que tengo, como premisa, debe de ser en una línea, de ahí que no lo termine por resolver.

```
Array.prototype.concatenar = function(vector) {
    let nuevoVector = this;
    nuevoVector.push.apply(this, vector);
    return nuevoVector;
};
```

No entiendo cómo resolver en un nuevo *array* u obtener un resultado de unirlos y devolverlo en una misma línea, he probado con el método `map` de recorrer el *vector* recibido y añadirlo al *vector* `this`, pero nada...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar el operador `...` con los `Arrays` :

```js
Array.prototype.concatenarArray = function(array){
  return [...this, ...array];
}

console.log([1, 2, 3].concatenarArray([1]));
```

[DOCUMENTACIÓN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Spread_operator)

**EDITO**

Puedes incluso hacer una función que concatene más de un `Array` :

```js
Array.prototype.concatenarArrays = function(...arrays){
  return [...this, ...arrays.reduce((anterior, actual)=>
    anterior.push(...actual) && anterior, [])];
}

console.log([1,2,3].concatenarArrays([1], [2,3]));
```

Comment: excelente respuesta!

Comment: @rnd Gracias! Aunque me faltaría poner un link a la documentación para ser exclente! =P Ahora edito!

Comment: Excelente, desconocía este operador en JavaScript, es justo lo que buscaba.

Comment: @dddenis Es relativamente nuevo en JavaScript, desde ECMASCRIPT 6 https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Spread_operator

Comment: @dddenis He editado la respuesta en el caso de que quieras concatenar el array con más de un array.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que lo que quieres hacer es esto..

- Creas el nuevo array.
- Empujas ambos arrays dentro del resultante.
- retornas el resultante.

```js
Array.prototype.concatenar = function(otro) {
    let nuevo = [];
    Array.prototype.push.apply(nuevo, this);
    Array.prototype.push.apply(nuevo, otro);
    return nuevo;
};

console.log([1,2,3].concatenar([4,5,6]));
```